# How to configure XAMPP to use with MSSQL?

Tags: php, xampp

I'm trying configure XAMPP to use with MSSQL. I'm following this: [Example](http://about-opensource.blogspot.in/2012/06/cake-php-231-with-sql-server-2005-or.html) but I still had success.

I copied the files: `php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll` and `php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll` to folder `c:\xampp\php\ext` and configured `php.ini` in `c:\xampp\php\php.ini`.

In `php.ini` I activated the extensions: `extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll` and `extension=php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll` and created PDO section. `[Pdo_sqlsrv]
pdo_sqlsrv.log_severity=-1`.

I am using XAMPP v3.2.1 and PHP 5.6.11

How could I make this works ?

Comment: What's the problem? any erro? did you try restart apache?

Comment: @rray in my php.info doesn't display section PDO of MSSQL and when I try connect throws exception `Error: Sqlserver driver is NOT enabled`

Comment: Your php version is 5.4? my xampp control is 3.2.1 and is php5.6.8

Comment: @rray `PHP Version 5.6.11`

Comment: You need download the  SQLSRV32.EXE for php5.6, [here](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/48079/91) has more instructions.

Comment: @rray very nice. Now works. I added extendsions `php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll` and `php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll`. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For PHP5.6 vou need download [SQLSRV32.EXE](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098), after it put the php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll and php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll on ext folder and finally register those extension on php.ini, like this:

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
```

Restart apache and try `phpinfo()`or you could use [`getAvailableDrivers()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.getavailabledrivers.php)

```
<?php
   echo "<pre>";
   print_r(PDO::getAvailableDrivers());
```

Comment: Thanks! By the way, you solved my problem (I coulnd't find a link to the PHP 5.6 sqlsrv drivers).

Comment: What's for php 7.3 ?

Answer (score 6):

After a long time...

I am 3 days with this problem, with me only resolved after adding the correct **versions** of the PDO driver on this [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/releases).

My windows is **64x**, but the XAMP is **86x**. I only noticed after running phpinfo()

Note that the version you must add to the \ext folder is not the operating system version but rather the xamp installation, just like the image below:

[image]