# XAMPP php 7 with mssql

Tags: php, sql-server, xampp

I need to use PHP7 with MsSQL. I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32981555/1678851) with the `php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64` and the `php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64` library, but inside `phpinfo` the `sqlsrv` it not showing.

```
$serverName = "serverName\sqlexpress"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"dbName", "UID"=>"userName", "PWD"=>"password");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Conexión establecida.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Conexión no se pudo establecer.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

Returns this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   sqlsrv_connect()

Could someone explain why I'm getting this error, and how to fix it?

Comment: My guess is your sqlsrv_connect function is undefined.

Comment: Hi @GrumpyCrouton, thanks for edit the question. The first problem is that phpinfo is not showing the sqlsrv library.  sqlsrv_connect function is undefined is a fact. That´s the answer that php is showing.

Comment: Well the sqlsrv library usually has to be explicitly defined in your php.ini

Comment: it is: 

extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll

Comment: Did you actually download the package and install it on your server? PHP can't activate a dll that doesn't exist

Comment: how to? I installed the .exe that microsoft offered

Comment: I'm not sure, I've never used the library, but I'm sure it is laid out pretty plainly in [the documentation for installing sqlsrv](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlsrv.setup.php)

Comment: it takes you to the same webpage https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098