# Issue loading SQL DLL PHP 5.6.32

Tags: php, sql-server, azure, dll, azure-sql-database

I've been trying to establish a connection between a PHP script and a Microsoft Azure SQL database but keep running into this same issue. I've tried `Xampp version 7.1.11 / PHP 7.1.11, 7.0.25 / PHP 7.0.25`, and now I am using 5.6.32 / PHP 5.6.32.

I've installed the [Microsoft Drivers for PHP for Microsoft SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx) and am using the `SQLSRV32.EXE` for Version 5.6.32 which is added to the `C:\xampp\php\ext` folder.

When I edit the `php.ini` file to add `extension=php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll` save and reboot apache in the php error log file I keep getting the error

`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll' - The specified module could not be found. in Unknown on line 0`

Each version of XAMPP that I've tried has done this. Can anyone lend an idea or a hand how I can get around this and complete my SQL connection using PHP to an Azure SQL database?

Comment: `php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll` must be in the extension directory from `php.ini` and `SQLSRV32.EXE` needs to be in a directory that's in the system path environment variable.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that to my question. I have placed all contents of `SQLSRX32.EXE` in the `C:\xampp\php\etx` directory.

Comment: Try steps provided on this article https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlphp/2015/05/11/getting-started-with-php-5-6-and-microsoft-sql-server-and-azure-sql-database/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after further tinkering and research, I've finally solved the issue I've mentioned above. Unfortunately, the common google search provides this [Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=20098) which only contains drivers up to PHP Version 7.0.XX. For `PHP Version 7.1.12` I've used the `thread safe1` `php_sqlsrv_71_ts_x64.dll` found here [Microsoft Drivers 4.3 for PHP for SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=55642). I'm not sure why it took me another three days to find this.

The connection to the Azure SQL Database now works, the steps are mentioned below. 
 
1. Acquire the correct SQL driver from Microsoft 
    -If you are using PHP Version 7.0 or earlier the drivers can be found [Here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=20098) 
    -If you are using PHP Version 7.1 the drivers can be found [Here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=55642) 
2. Install [Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50420) 
3. Install required `.dll's` to the `php\ext` folder. `eg. C:\php\ext` 
4. Edit the `php.ini` file and ensure the `extension_dir=` points to the `C:\php\ext` folder that you placed the downloaded `.dll's` (drivers) in. 
5. Add `extension=required .dll name` to the php.ini file approximately line 890. In my case this is `extension=php_sqlsrv_71_ts_x64.dll` 
6. Save `php.ini` and restart `Apache`.

The PHP script I've used to test my connection is as follows: 
 `sqltest.php`

```
    $connectionInfo = array("UID" => "USERNAME", "pwd" => "PASSWORD", "Database" => "DBNAME", "LoginTimeout" => 30, "Encrypt" => 1, "TrustServerCertificate" => 0);
    $serverName = "SERVERNAME";
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

    if (sqlsrv_errors($conn)) {
        die('Failed to connect to Azure SQL: '.sqlsrv_errors());
    } else {
        echo "Connection to Microsoft Azure SQL Server has succeeded! <br /><br />";
    }

    $tsql = "SELECT * FROM [Users];";
    $getResults = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql);
    echo ("Reading data from table <br />" . PHP_EOL);

    if ($getResults == FALSE)
        echo(sqlsrv_errors());
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($getResults, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo ($row['Id'] . " " . $row['Name'] . " " . $row['Username'] . " " . $row['Password'] . "<br /> " . PHP_EOL);
    }
    sqlsrv_free_stmt($getResults);
    ?>
```

Further information is provided by Microsoft [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query-php)

Thanks again for all of the helpful input from everyone above.

Answer (score 1):

First, open a `phpinfo()` and search for the line **Thread safety**. If it says enabled, then you should use the Thread-Safe DLLs instead.

[image]

- [How to configure XAMPP to use with MSSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32978554/how-to-configure-xampp-to-use-with-mssql/32981555#32981555)