# How to configure XAMPP v. 3.2.2 (PHP 7.2) with MSSQL?

Tags: php, sql-server, apache

I am running into a bit of an issue trying to configure MSSQL with XAMPP. I used [this video](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjIw9GOs8bYAhXi5IMKHTMoCKQQtwIIJzAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DhxfdbnpOqSI&usg=AOvVaw1vbWuhL1qWh7ZOLqAgoTg3) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32978554/how-to-configure-xampp-to-use-with-mssql) to setup MSSQL with XAMPP. I went over to MSPHPSQL releases [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/releases) and downloaded the 7.2 version as I am running XAMPP 3.2.2 with PHP 7.2. I have placed the `php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_ts.dll` and `php_sqlsrv_72_ts.dll` in the "XAMPP\php\ext" folder. Then, I went over to the `php.ini` file and added both `extension=pdo_sqlsrv_72_ts` and `extension=sqlsrv_72_ts` beneath the other extensions.

However, when I start up the Apache Server and navigate to the PHPInfo, I do not see the `pdo_sqlsrv_72_ts` nor the `sqlsrv_72_ts` listed. I was wondering if anyone could help me figure out why it is not showing up in the PHPInfo as I believe I have made a mistake somewhere and that is why it is not showing up under PHPInfo. Perhaps I used the wrong files or made a mistake when adding in the "extension=" part. Thanks in advance for any help and I appreciate it.

**EDIT** My [PHPInfo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qqf25.jpg) after I made the changes

**EDIT 2** With help from jetblack, we managed to solve it. Turns out I downloaded the 64-bit files of the SQLSRV extension. Downloading and installing the 32-bit versions made it work. Thank up for all the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems "php_" prefixes are missing in your configuration. Try like the following:

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_72_ts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_ts.dll
```

Also check prerequisites list. You may need to download ODBC driver.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50420

Also please verify if you downloaded correct version. (32 bit or 64 bit)

Comment: I thought that might have been the case but when I looked in the `php.ini` file, I saw the following: `If you wish to have an extension loaded automatically, use the following syntax: extension=modulename`



It also stated the following: `The syntax used in previous PHP versions ('extension=<ext>.so' and 'extension='php_<ext>.dll') is supported for legacy reasons and may be deprecated in a future PHP major version. So, when it is possible, please move to the new ('extension=<ext>) syntax.`

Comment: Allright, if you copy-paste your phpinfo() output it would be easier to resolve the problem.

Comment: Do you mean if I have `extension=php_sqlsrv_72_ts.dll` before `extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_ts.dll`? If so, I made the change but still could not get it to show up in PHPInfo.

Comment: What is the value of "Thread Safety" in phpinfo() page? Also which operating system do you have?

Comment: If you are sure that you use correct version (64bit or 32 bit), you may be editing wrong php.ini file.

Comment: I did not realize there is another version of the php.ini file. You might be right I could be editing the wrong file. Do you know where the other "php.ini" file is located?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162697/discussion-between-jetblack-and-vectorconvoy).