# Connecting to MS SQL Server via XAMPP PHP undefined function sqlsrv_connect

Tags: php, sql-server, xampp

I'm new to PHP (and web servers for that matter).
Here's what I'm dealing with.

Database Server: MS SQL Server 2014 Express

Web Server: XAMPP v3.2.2

PHP: PHP Version 7.3.0

I'm trying to connect to my database via PHP.

Here's what I've done thus far.

1) Since I need drivers for PHP Version 7.3.0, I got them at https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/releases (Windows-7.3.zip)
There are four files in the folder.

2) I've placed all possible combinations of those files in C:\xampp\php\ext and added/deleted corresponding lines like "extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_nts"
I don't know if it matters, but I placed all the lines just under all the other extensions (the last on the list is "extension=shmop").

3) Then I've proceeded to http://localhost/dashboard/phpinfo.php, but there was no changes on this page. And my connection attempt results in the same error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I searched, and i found out this:
https://bendustries.co/wp/setting-up-xampp-to-work-with-mssql/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to configure XAMPP v. 3.2.2 (PHP 7.2) with MSSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48139885/how-to-configure-xampp-v-3-2-2-php-7-2-with-mssql)

Comment: There's no need to try them all, just use the one that matches your system specs. And you also need to install the appropriate Microsoft drivers, as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/step-1-configure-development-environment-for-php-development?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: I guess there might be other XAMPP users who are just beginning to explore this whole thing. So for those who might per chance stumble upon the same issue, the solution was simple. Even though my system is x64, I had to use drivers for x86(x32) that you can get at https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/releases

Thank you everyone, and best of luck configuring your connection!