# Connect XAMPP to microsoft sql server management studio 2012 in one machine

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I cannot connect my php to Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2012 using XAMPP. I am using separate database (not phpmyadmin) I already turned off mysql in XAMPP.

my xampp and 
The database has no password as I have tried accessing mysql.
Error below appears when i run the php code.
 **Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.**

My code:

```
$server = 'localhost';
$username= 'sa';
$password = '';
$db= 'CASA';
$conn= mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password ,$db);
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you mean connect to MySQL or Microsoft SQL server because if you planning to connect MSSQL you need to use [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) not mysqli because mysqli meant for connecting to MySQL only

Comment: I am planning to use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2012 because my data are already there. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to install or [enable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32978554/how-to-configure-xampp-to-use-with-mssql)(if already installed) the [sqlserver php driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/download-drivers-php-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) and then you could try something like below which i have just taken from [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/how-to-connect-using-sql-server-authentication?view=sql-server-2017)

```
<?php  
   $serverName = "(local)";   
   $database = "AdventureWorks";  

   // Get UID and PWD from application-specific files.   
   $uid = file_get_contents("C:\AppData\uid.txt");  
   $pwd = file_get_contents("C:\AppData\pwd.txt");  

   try {  
      $conn = new PDO( "sqlsrv:server=$serverName;Database = $database", $uid, $pwd);   
      $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );   
   }  

   catch( PDOException $e ) {  
      die( "Error connecting to SQL Server" );   
   }  

   echo "Connected to SQL Server\n";  

   $query = 'select * from Person.ContactType';   
   $stmt = $conn->query( $query );   
   while ( $row = $stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) ){   
      print_r( $row );   
   }  

   // Free statement and connection resources.   
   $stmt = null;   
   $conn = null;   
?>
```

I hope it helps you

Comment: Does the SQL php driver need to be installed to the SQL server or XAMPP? Thanks.

Comment: Download the driver and extract it to a created folder and copy and paste the `.dll` that match your `php` to the `C:\xampp\php\ext` directory and finally enable them in the `php.ini` file.